# Sitecore Stimulsoft Report Designer Does not Support Adding Filter Variables

Tags: sitecore, stimulsoft

I am developing some Reports in Sitecore using Stimulsoft report designer and I need to have a filter like in this report http://web.stimulsoft.com/default.aspxreportname=ParametersSelectingCountry

I had a look at the video tutorial on creating a filter like this.
http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/videos?id=69&tags=web,parameters

However when I create a new variable using report designer in Sitecore it does not allow me the option to select "Request from User" as in the video tutorial. Also in addition to that there are many missing features in that create a new variable window compared to video tutorial. Am I using a older report designer with Sitecore ?

Comment: What Designer do you use? and version?

Comment: Sitecore version is 6.5 and I am using the default designer available.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will answer your question, but here it is.

I found that the web report designer that comes with Sitecore (even 7) is not really good and a lot of things seems not to be working correctly.

One way would be to get the report suite and use the standalone report designer if possible or manually edit the report definition files.